# How do you flatten a for-comprehension with traverse in scala cats effect?

Tags: scala, scala-cats, for-comprehension, cats-effect

I have some code structurally identical to this and I'm not sure the best way to clean it up? The trivial IOs and additions are there so that the example compiles without needing additional methods.

I'd really like to not have it be so nested, is there a way to have a single for comprehension that supports both IO and List? I know theres OptionT for the option variant of this problem, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent ListT.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

```
import cats.Traverse
import cats.effect.IO
import cats.implicits._

def exampleDoingSomeThings: IO[Unit] = for {
    ids <- IO.pure(List(1, 2, 3))
    _ <- ids.traverse[IO, Unit](id => for {
      users <- IO.pure(List(id + 4, id + 5, id + 6))
      data <- IO(id + 7)
      otherData <- IO(id + 8)
      _ <- users.traverse[IO, Unit](ud => for {
        innerData <- IO(id + ud)
        innerState <- IO(ud + 9)
        _ <- if (innerState > 15) for {
          _ <- IO(println(s"action1: $id $ud"))
          _ <- IO(println(s"action2: $id $ud"))
        } yield () else IO.pure()
      } yield ())
    } yield ())
  } yield ()

exampleDoingSomeThings.unsafeRunSync
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/S79H1ZI/0

Comment: https://typelevel.org/cats/faq.html#listt

Comment: How about extracting out to smaller methods on the inner parts? That way you only ever "see" a single level of nesting.

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up going with. A bit disspointed I can't have it read more like a flattened comprehension. Thanks for the link to the FAQ!

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, you could extract your methods to sub methods. However, if you find that is not enough, you can use libraries like [FS2](https://github.com/functional-streams-for-scala/fs2) or [Monix](https://github.com/monix/monix) to make your life easier. Its really good for handling IO + List things.

You can visualize a stream as a list of items that emits one by one. So, you only need to deal with one at a time.

The above example can be translated as (excluding unused variables):

Monix:

```
def monixThings: Observable[Unit] = for {
  id <- Observable.fromIterable(List(1, 2, 3))
  ud <- Observable.fromIterable(List(id + 4, id + 5, id + 6))
  innerState <- Observable.pure(ud + 9)
  _ <- Observable.fromTask {
    if (innerState > 15) {
      for {
        _ <- Task.delay(println(s"action1: $id $ud"))
        _ <- Task.delay(println(s"action2: $id $ud"))
      } yield ()
    } else {
      Task.unit
    }
  }
} yield ()

monixThings.completedL.runSyncUnsafe()
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/BDKbGCq/0

FS2:

```
import cats.effect.IO
import fs2.Stream

object FS2Example extends App {

  def fs2Things = for {
    id <- Stream.emits(List(1, 2, 3))
    ud <- Stream.emits(List(id + 4, id + 5, id + 6))
    innerState <- Stream.emit(ud + 9)
    _ <- Stream.eval {
      if (innerState > 15) {
        for {
          _ <- IO(println(s"action1: $id $ud"))
          _ <- IO(println(s"action2: $id $ud"))
        } yield ()
      } else {
        IO.unit
      }
    }
  } yield ()

  fs2Things.compile.drain.unsafeRunSync()
}
```